# How to tell NHibernate always to force quoted identifiers?

Tags: nhibernate

As the title: How would I tell NHibernate, once and for all, that all table and column names are to be quoted in the SQL it generates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've not tried this, but as far as i can determine based on the [documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy) a custom implementation of the naming strategy allows you to rewrite the table/column names thus also enables you to quote them.

Comment: this references a broken link.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try:

```
SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(configuration);
```

Comment: This is what worked for me 100%. The neat thing is that NHibernate only quotes reserved keywords, not *everything*. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to quote the column names, at least for postgresql.

Comment: This not working with oracle either! (Oracle.DataAccess Provider)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">auto-quote</property>
```

to your NHibernate configuration.