# What is the NHibernate Mapping.ByCode equivalent of the "hbm2ddl.keywords" setting?

Tags: nhibernate

I just ran into a situation related to this SO question: [How to tell NHibernate always to force quoted identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199896/how-to-tell-nhibernate-always-to-force-quoted-identifiers)

My entity has an "Order" property, and NH chokes trying to create the database. I am using the new Mapping.ByCode feature of NHibernate 3.2, and its not entirely clear where I need to apply the `hbm2dll.keywords` setting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/06/24/auto-quote-table-column-names.aspx

When you have an instance of a configured configuration (just before call `BuildSessionFactory`) you can execute:

`SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(configuration);`